# return 0 implicit

Tags: c++

The last week on the ACM ICPC Mexico competition, I missed a "return 0" on a C++ program. For this reason we got punished with 20 minutes.

I had read that the standard does not oblige us to write it at the end of a main function. It is implicit, isn't it? How can I prove it?

We were using a Fedora system with a G++ compiler.

Comment: Are you sure you want this tagged "C" as well as "C++"? Your question seems to only pertain to C++. FWIW, C99 provides implicit return 0 in main, earlier standards of C do not.

Comment: This reminds me of the time I was given a 9/10 on a math assignment because I didn't write the date at the top right of the page and underline it.

Comment: Did you miss the `return 0` in `main` or in a different function? It is only implicit in `main`.

Comment: @FredOverflow. I miss it in main function.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You refer to the C++ Standard, chapter 3.6.1 paragraph 5:

> A return statement in main has the
>   effect of leaving the main function
>   (destroying any objects with automatic
>   storage duration) and calling
>   exit with the return value as the
>   argument. If control reaches the end
>   of main without encountering a return
>   statement, the effect is that of
>   executing `return 0;`

If you haven't got the Standard at hand, you can show then the paragraph in a Working Draft. Here is one for c++98, which already had this defined.

You can learn more [here](http://www.kuzbass.ru:8086/docs/isocpp/basic.html#basic.start.main).

Comment: The judging is automated at the ACM competitions. So for some reason it  didn't compile because of the lack of return statement.  Could this of been a result of an old compiler?

Answer (score 0):

You could show them the line in [Bjarne Stroustrup's book](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/3rd.html) defining the standard where it states it: since it is the canonical standard for the language, it is not open for debate. Unfortunately I don't have a copy to look it up myself.

Comment: Um. That book doesn't define the standard. The standard is BS ISO/IEC 14882:1998 plus the technical corrigenda. If the two disagree then Bjarne's book is wrong until the full standards body decides otherwise (of course he's on that body himself, so disagreements tend to be typos...)

Comment: I agree with the actual answer, by the way - I'd expect that book to be accepted as accurate in a matter like this by anyone who knows what they're doing. It describes the standard accurately afaik. It just doesn't "define" the standard, so it is in theory open to debate.