# getchar() returns immediately

Tags: c, getchar

I'm programming C in Visual Studio 2013 Express for Desktop, and when I use getchar() it terminates immediately.

Here's the code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num1, num2;
    printf("Enter first number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("Enter second number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    printf("Result: %d\n", num1 + num2);
    printf("Press any key to exit...");
    getchar();
}
```

After the last string is printed, the program exits immediately without waiting for any key press, even though I've used getchar().

Should getchar() wait for a key press (character input), and the move on?
Why does it automatically goes on and exits the program, without waiting for key press?

Comment: 'cos there's a char still left in the input buffer.

Comment: This question comes up on StackOverflow about once a day. I'll see if I can find some duplicates...

Comment: I think this is a repetition of [using getch() to hold command prompt open Visual C++ 2010
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502476/using-getch-to-hold-command-prompt-open-visual-c-2010)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to call `getchar();` twice in the end, or to use [`fgets();`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) instead.

The problem is, that when you enter a char on the console, you do in fact enter an additional newline each time.