# What is the reason behind the "False" output of this code?

Tags: c, gcc, comparison, sizeof, unsigned

This C code gives output "False" and the `else` block is executing.

The value of `sizeof(int)` is 4 but the value of `sizeof(int) > -1` is 0.

I don't understand what is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    if (sizeof(int) > -1 )
    {
       printf("True");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("False");
    }
    printf("\n%d", (sizeof(int)) ); //output: 4
    printf("\n%d", (sizeof(int) > -1) ); //output: 0
}
```

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings.  You should get some.

Comment: `sizeof (int) > -1` converts `-1` to unsigned and is the same as `sizeof (int) > 4294967295`

Comment: ok, -1 is converted to some MAX value due to the fact that sizeof (int) return "unsigned" type value. Right?

Comment: If am not mistaken what happen is that -1 is 11111...1 in signed complement for 2, if you tell the compiler that it is unsigned, than  11111.....1 the last digit will not be 4294967295

Comment: Why it converts -1 to the equivalent? Why not it converts " sizeof(int) " to int type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is −1 > sizeof(int)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100365/why-is-%e2%88%921-sizeofint)

Comment: 1. [`void main()` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/995714). 2. You have UB when printing `sizeof` with `%d`. You [must use `%zu` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714). And there are lots of duplicates: [Why is (sizeof(int) > -1) false? (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34151309/995714)

Comment: `void main()` is not wrong. Otherwise I have to write extra line `return 0`.

Comment: @DeepakGautam it's wrong. It's only valid in some extensions like Turbo C or MSVC, or in a *freestanding* environment, otherwise it's completely forbidden. Read the other question for more info. And *Otherwise I have to write extra line `return 0`* is also **wrong**. In C99 a **`return 0` is implicitly added** if you don't write one. See [Why does main() not need a return statement? (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13232784/995714)

Comment: yes I know, I forgot it. thanks @phuclv

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `sizeof(int) > -1` test is comparing two **unsigned** integers. This is because the `sizeof` operator returns a `size_t` value, which is of `unsigned` type, so the `-1` value is converted to its 'equivalent' representation as an unsigned value, which will actually be the *largest possible* value for an `unsigned int`.

To fix this, you need to *explicitly* cast the `sizeof` value to a (signed) `int`:

```c
    if ((int)sizeof(int) > -1) {
        printf("True");
    }
```

Comment: Why it converts -1 to the equivalent? Why not it converts " sizeof(int) " to int type?

Comment: Because the rules say so:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons

Comment: @abelenky Indeed (although that post is for C++). From [this C11 Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (6.3.1.8): *Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
integer type.*

Comment: so it's implicit behavior. Thanks @abelenky

Comment: −1 is converted by value, not representation, to 2^N−1, where N is the number of bits in `size_t`. For example, −1 has different representations in two’s complement (111…111), one’s complement (111…110), and sign-and-magnitude (100…001), but `(size_t) -1` is always 2^N−1 per the C standard. Also note that `size_t` can be narrower than `int`, in which case it is promoted and the `-1` is not, and `sizeof(int) > -1` evaluates to true.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are correct (of course). Yet my proposed solution will work, even in the ***very*** rare case that `size_t` is narrower than `int` (although, then it will admittedly be superfluous).

Answer (score 3):

The [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) operator gives a [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) result.

And `size_t` is an *unsigned* type while `-1` is not.

That leads to problem when [converting](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) `-1` to the same type as `size_t` (`-1` turns into a very large number, much larger than `sizeof(int)`).

Since `sizeof` returns an unsigned value (which by definition can't be negative), a comparison like yours makes no sense. And besides standard C doesn't allow zero-sized objects or types, so even `sizof(any_type_or_expression) > 0` will always be true.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be careful when mixing signed and unsigned values in expressions (and `sizeof` yields a `size_t`, which is unsigned).

In a fair number of cases (including this one) the compiler will convert both values to the same type before carrying out operations on them--and when you mix signed and unsigned values, that same type will usually be the unsigned type involved. So what happens in this case is that the `-1` gets converted to an unsigned--and when converted to an unsigned value, `-1` always converts to the largest value that unsigned type can hold.

From there, the rest is probably fairly clear, I'd guess.